# Write winston log messages in order (in time sequence)?

Tags: javascript, logging, winston

It's hard to read log files that aren't sequential. Is it possible to have winston's log messages appear in time-sequence? (Or, what are the factors that control when Winston writes entries?)

For example, I have a log output that includes a date/time with milliseconds.

```
2016-02-25 21:34:07.671 INFO  ...
2016-02-25 21:34:07.692 INFO  ...
2016-02-25 21:34:07.690 DEBUG  ...   <-- time goes backwards
2016-02-25 21:34:07.692 INFO  ...
2016-02-25 21:34:07.691 DEBUG  ...   <-- and again
2016-02-25 21:34:07.692 DEBUG  ...
2016-02-25 21:34:07.692 DEBUG  ...
```

NB: The code that generates the timestamps is at: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/802